# Locating a substring in Field Calculator using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcmap

I have what should be a fairly straightforward operation failing in ArcGIS Pro 2.4, and cannot for the life of me work out why.

If the field "assettype" contains a portion of the search string, then set the value of assettype_groupup to the value I return.

Eg, if "assetttype" contains the string "Building |Residential |Large ", and I test whether it contains the term "Residential", and that evaluates to true, then return the string "Residential".

Currently the code does not seem to be returning any result / has no effect, and appears to run too quickly (2-3 seconds for 3,000,000 lines).

If I try a ternary statement, which means using a single term at a time, it seems to work just fine. I'd rather not take this approach as the if/elif possibilities could wind up being extensive in nature and I'd like to run the routine only once.

Can you see any obvious issues with the setup below

```
#Target Field Name 
assettype_groupup

#Expression
func(!assettype!)

# Code block
def func(input):
    if 'Residential' in input:
        return 'Residential'
    elif 'Industrial/Utilities' in input:
        return 'Industrial/Utilities'
    elif 'Transport/Infrastructure' in input:
        return 'Transport/Infrastructure'
    elif 'Conservation/National Park' in input:
        return 'Conservation/National Park'
    elif 'Recreational/Open Space' in input:
        return 'Recreational/Open Space'
    elif 'Mixed Use' in input:
        return 'Mixed Use'
    elif 'Community Use' in input:
        return 'Community Use'
    elif 'Rural/Primary Production' in input:
        return 'Rural/Primary Production'
    elif 'Special Use' in input:
        return 'Special Use'
    elif 'Unknown' in input:
        return 'Unknown'
    else:
        ''
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code that you say is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with ArcGIS Pro, but do know Python fairly well.

In Python you should avoid naming variables or arguments the same as any
built-ins, and `input()` is the name of a built-in function. Also, the line after
the final `else:`, should be `return ''`. Since that's not the case, your
function will effectively return `None` when there are no matches, **not** the
empty string `''` (assuming that's what you intended).

With that in mind, the following would be a better way to write the function that would avoid both of the issues mentioned above:

```
TARGETS = (
    'Residential',
    'Industrial/Utilities',
    'Transport/Infrastructure',
    'Conservation/National Park',
    'Recreational/Open Space',
    'Mixed Use',
    'Community Use',
    'Rural/Primary Production',
    'Special Use',
    'Unknown',
)


# Code block
def func(info):
    for target in TARGETS:
        if target in info:
            return target
    else:  # Nothing matched.
        return ''
```

A more advanced, slightly shorter and likely much faster, way to do would be by using Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) regular expression module which is part of its standard library:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, TARGETS)))

# Code block
def func(info):
    mo = regex.search(info)
    return mo.group(0) if mo else ''
```

In Python 3.8.0+ it could be shortened a little bit more by taking advantage of [PEP 572's](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) new syntax for [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) using `:=` (aka the "walrus" operator) which was added beginning in that version:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, TARGETS)))

def func(info):
    return mo.group(0) if (mo := regex.search(info)) else ''  # Py 3.8.0+
```

Comment: This is exactly the information I required to find the solution, thank you. 

For those who might find this in the future:
ArcMap with Python 2 expressions generally coped with the code I had in the opening post. Python 3 with ArcGIS Pro, doesn't. 

martineau's post coes in the codeblock, and the expression should be func(!fieldname!)